# Remove Skype start up program

Tags: boot

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Satellite-Pro-L50-A
Memory 15.6 GiB
Processor Intel® Core™ i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz × 8 
Graphics Intel® Haswell Mobile
Gnome 3.28.2
OS Type 64-bit

Hi I would like to stop Skype from starting up automatically whenever I boot my computer. If Skype does not allow this then I want remove Skype completely

Comment: Is Skype listed in your Startup Applications control panel?

Comment: please explain how to find start up applications panel

Comment: It's in your control panels (settings), top right corner of your screen, near the shutdown button. It's also in your desktop search (the little grid at the bottom of your launch bar OR your keyboard's Super/Windows Key), start typing 'startup' in the text box and it will be one of the alternatives.

Comment: thanks but when I go to settings I still cannot find it sorry I am so dumb I did a search from inside settings

Answer (score 4):

Start Skype. Go to Tools / Settings / General and toggle off "Automatically start Skype".

Answer (score 0):

Run in the terminal:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

Then uncheck Skype:

[image]

You could also try using terminal remove it from user's autostart directory:

```
rm ~/.config/autostart/skype*.desktop
```

or better move it somewhere instead of removing.

But if you follow *Organic Marble's* answer, skype will do it for you by itself.